# How to connect a virtual NIC in one QEMU-KVM instance to a virtual NIC in another QEMU-KVM instance without a bridge

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, qemu, tap

Is there a way to connect a Virtual NIC one QEMU-KVM instance to a Virtual NIC on another QEMU-KVM instance. I want to be able to do this efficiently and it may be possible that the 2 instances could be on local or remote machines.

I understand the use of TAP interfaces tied a bridge. But I am trying to create point to point connections between Virtual NICs in different QEMU-KVM instances

Answer (score 2):

Qemu simply maps the v-NIC to a tap, whatever you plug the tap into is up to you. Bridge is the obvious choice, but there's also openvswitch, for example.

Comment: I really want to to connect the TAP1(connected to vNIC1/VM1) to TAP2(connected to vNIC2/VM2) back to back. Locally and possibly remotely. Can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: what is wrong with using a bridge between the two? It doesn't have to also use a physical NIC, unless you need to get out of the host